# Set default value for signal from input

Tags: vhdl, fpga, spartan

Is there any way to set default value of signal *from input*?
Like this:

```
entity NORMAL_CONTROL is
    Port (INPUT : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0));
end NORMAL_CONTROL;

architecture Behavioral of NORMAL_CONTROL is

    signal S : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0) := INPUT;

begin

end Behavioral;
```

This code does not have error but it apparently doesn't set default value for `S`!

Comment: What do you mean by "default value"? In which case should this value take effect for `S`? What you have written is an *initial value* which may or may not be synthesizable.

Comment: we can set default value statically for S. like this:  ```signal S : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0) := "00001111";```  but I want to set default value for the signal ***dynamically from the input***

Comment: Yes, but what do you expect that to *mean*? Can you draw a schematic diagram of the hardware you expect this do describe?

Comment: Do you simply want to *assign* `INPUT` to `S`? Then write it in the architecture body: `S <= INPUT;`

Comment: "it apparently doesn't set default value for S" - how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: I want to program 2 traffic lights with state machine design. The first value of red light and green light are inputs. First I have to set these inputs as the default for the signals, then with the clock edge, I reduce the signal values.

Comment: when i synthesized and simulated ,i saw the value of signal is UUUUUUUU instead of input number.

Comment: That's probably because `INPUT` itself is initially undefined.

Comment: Why does it matter if it is initially UUUU ? after 1 delta `INPUT` will have the value assigned to it from the external connection.

Comment: Clarify. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.4 Elaboration of a declarative part, 14.4.1 General "In certain cases, the elaboration of a declarative item involves the evaluation of expressions that appear within the declarative item. The value of any object denoted by a primary  in such an expression shall be defined at the time the primary is read (see  6.5.2). ...".  The primary INPUT is evaluated during the elaboration of S. INPUT's default value during elaboration is used. [You can define INPUT's value in a default expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFNOW.jpg) at elaboration, that's not dynamic.